# how to get the rating value on click on stars

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery rating plugin.
in all examples they have a submit button near to rating stars.
so that submit button do this.form.serialize.
but i want to save the rating to db without clicking on the submit button.
i am not giving submit button to users.
if anybody has done this already can you help me please.
these are the jquery examples.

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing

Comment: I'm out of flags for today, but I was on a roll. Too localized.

Comment: Doesn't example 3-a on the page you linked give you exactly this behaviour? It allows you to auto-submit the results when the user clicks the starts.

Comment: @GGG I'm not sure I agree. It's definitely not inconceivable that other users of the plugin will want to submit the rating without requiring the user to click an additional element to actually submit the form.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist look how many [star rating plugins](https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+Star+Rating+Plugin) there are for jQuery. I'm guessing the number of people using this particular plugin, needing this particular modification, and lacking the expertise to do it themselves (or the patience to find another more suitable plugin) is pretty low.

Comment: thanks, i missed that example. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the source of the page and I found this:

```
 $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
    //called when clicked 
    callback: function(value, link){
       // 'this' is the hidden form element holding the current value
       // 'value' is the value selected
       // 'element' points to the link element that received the click.
       $(this.form).ajaxSubmit();
    }
 });
```

Hope this helps